# Is this resistor network simulation OK?

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit

[image]

In circuits as shown in picture 1 there lies a short wire in between as marked in picture two. In my attempt to find the direction of the current flow on that kind of example circuit, shouldn't the current choose to flow in either 22000 Ω or 1200 Ω, after it has passed through the short wire, after passing through 82000 Ω and 5600 Ω? either 22000 Ω or 1200 Ω is discarded based on the greater voltage on each of the endpoint of the marked wire.

but here in this simulation, I have the current flow all over the circuit.

[image]

https://streamable.com/5wrb6b

I modified the resistors to flip over the greater voltage point on the marked wire, and I still see the current flowing all over.

[image]

https://streamable.com/5vdvlw

Is the simulation wrong or am I missing something? if I am missing anything, can you tell me what's that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is to think current only takes one path or the path of least resistance. It does not work like that. It takes all available paths. Which is why you can have a light bulb and hair dryer in the same dual socket and they both keep working even if hair dryer is turned on and takes much more current than the light bulb.

Based on Ohm's law, you can see that any time there is some voltage difference over some value resistor, the corresponding current must flow through the resistor.

Then, using Kirchhoff's voltage and current laws, both the voltages in the circuit must add up, and also the currents entering and exiting a node.

And using the rules for equivalent resistances for series and parallel reaistances these currents can be calculated. Also using the voltage divider rule allows to make a guess which way the current would flow based on calculated voltages of the nodes when the short circuit is removed. Sometimes, the current can be zero too.

Comment: i am speaking of a very ideal scenario. there would be zero resistance on the wire with no external resistor added in it.

Comment: @dandelionseeds You are missing the point. There will be current in your zero-ohm wire linking the two voltage dividers, if the voltage dividers have non-equal voltages which the wire between them must balance.

Answer (score 1):

In the simulation, the wire has been replaced by an invisible 0Ω resistor. That's how you can see the current flow in it. Otherwise, "wires" in schematics are nodes, so everything connected together by a wire is the same thing. There is no concept of current flow within a node. So, simulators check the topology of the circuit and any time there is a branch in the *graphical* wiring, a 0Ω resistor is added in the "middle" of the branching wire.

So, to understand what's going on in the simulation, you have to add that 0Ω resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQhMiR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the simulation, the current meter (ammeter) is a zero-ohm resistor that displays the current that flows through it. Real ammeters have non-zero shunt resistance.

You can see that about 1% of the current flows through the "bridge" between the branches (0.03mA vs 3mA).

Comment: does the current actually flow there or not?

Comment: @dandelionseeds As you can see in the simulation shown, the current does actually flow through the branch on which AM2 is installed. The current is, as I've said, about 1% of the overall current, but is definitely not zero.

Comment: what if the wire had no resistance at all? ain't real life case, but just imagine the wire had exactly 0 resistance.

Comment: The wire has no resistance. I just inserted an ammeter in it so that you can see the current that flows through it. A wire with higher resistance than zero would see slightly less current flowing through it in fact. Wire has zero resistance and there is current flowing through it. I hope that’s clear. I’m not sure what your question is at this point. The simulation - yours, mine, and the one you can calculate by hand give identical results.

Comment: @dandelionseeds Basically you took literally the simplification that currents always take the path of least resistance. That is basically false. They flow through various paths, in rough proportion to conductance of the path (reciprocal of resistance). The most conductive path (peats resistive) will carry most of the current, but not all of it if other paths exist. And in your circuit there are multiple paths.